# How to delete a connection using curl and HTTP API in RabbitMQ

Tags: curl, rabbitmq

It is given in the HTTP API documentation of RabbitMQ that /api/connections/name can be used to delete connection. But `curl -i -u guest:guest -X "DELETE" http://localhost:15672/api/connections/ --data-urlencode "${conn_name}"` gives:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
allow: HEAD, GET, OPTIONS
content-length: 0
date: Wed, 12 Dec 2018 16:54:48 GMT
server: Cowboy
vary: origin
```

However GET is working. `curl -i -u guest:guest -X GET http://localhost:15672/api/connections/ --data-urlencode "${conn_name}"` gives

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
cache-control: no-cache
content-length: 1175
content-type: application/json
date: Wed, 12 Dec 2018 16:48:32 GMT
server: Cowboy
vary: accept, accept-encoding, origin

[{"auth_mechanism":"PLAIN",...
```

Comment: It is not using the --data-urlencode "${conn_name}" argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please carefully re-read the [API documentation](https://cdn.rawgit.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/v3.7.9/priv/www/api/index.html) for `/api/connections` and `DELETE`. You will notice that the correct URI for this operation is `/api/connections/name`, where `name` is the name of your connection. The `--data-urlencode` option for `curl` is mainly for `POST` requests (but see the `-G` `curl` option). Your `GET` request is actually returning **all** connections.

So, if your connection name is "My RabbitMQ Connection", you will first have to URL-encode it, and create the correct URI:

```
curl -4vvvu guest:guest -X DELETE 'localhost:15672/api/connections/My%20RabbitMQ%20Connection'
```

Comment: In addition to reserved characters, you also have to URL encode the `>` character (to `%3E`), which shows up in autogenerated RMQ connection names.